# Is this system affected by CVE-2019-7304?

Tags: security, snap, root, malware

I am analyzing a system that since a month shows two new users in the login screen.

After some research I stumbled over the exploit of snap: [CVE-2019-7304](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2019-7304)

I checked the passwd file and found a new user in there.

However, the currently installed version of snapd should not be affected by the exploit.

Yet I found the following journal logs:
[image]
(Sorry for screenshot as I could not copy text.)

`snapd` was in version `2.57.6` at time of check. But it was upgraded in the meantime.

1. Does that mean the system was/ is affected?
2. If snapd was directly upgraded afterwards that still means the system is vulnerable due to the newly created user, right?

Comment: Check under "status" on the CVE link - it indicates which package versions were patched in which OS.  Compare that against the version of snapd installed on your computer (see `apt info snapd | grep Version`).  If that version of snapd is higher than or equal to the version specified in the CVE notes for where it was fixed, you SHOULD be patched already against the system.  Before you do anything you have to validate the version of the package on your system before 'assuming' something is still vulnerable.

Comment: `snapd` was in version 2.57.6 at time of check. But it was upgraded in the meantime.